# WorkManager constraint (setRequiresCharging) doesn't work on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-workmanager

I'm setting up **OneTimeWorkRequest** with a constraint -"**setRequiresCharging**" but this work request doesn't call the doWork method when I switch the battery status to charging from discharging.

This problem exists on the emulator and works fine on my real device, so I am thinking that it might not work on all devices.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WorkManager mWorkManager;
    public static final String TAG="MainActivityTag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
        setupWorkRequest();
    }

    private void setupWorkRequest() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupWorkRequest: " + "setting request");
        // Create charging constraint
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .build();
        OneTimeWorkRequest chargerListen = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                .Builder(ChargerListener.class)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();
        mWorkManager.enqueue(chargerListen);
    }
}
```

```
public class ChargerListener extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "ChargerListenerTag";

     public ChargerListenerWork(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams){
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork: "+"Charger Connected");
        // do some work when connected
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

In logcat I expect the charger connected, it works on my Samsung device but doesn't work on the android emulator.

Comment: Same problem for me, and it doesn't work on emulator, as well as on any real devices with Android 10 or 11, including Pixel 4. 
On emulator, it seems to start work when charge level changes above 90%. 
This isn't really what the function "setRequiresCharging" promises.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried with the WorkManager sample from the [codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager) (using WorkManager v2.1.x) and it works when I set the correct battery and charging status on the emulator (I'm using v29.0.9-5537588):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out that in order for the condition `setRequiresCharging(true)` to take effect and `doWork()` to be triggered, two things should happen:

1. The device (or emulator in this case) should be plugged (to power or USB)
2. And this is key - the battery charge level should increase by at least 1%

The easiest way to achieve this IMO is with ADB like this:

1. `adb shell dumpsys battery set level 42` - Sets the battery level to 42%
2. `adb shell dumpsys battery set ac 1` - Emulate the device plugged to AC
3. `adb shell dumpsys battery set level 43` - Increase battery level - triggers worker

It should be possible to achieve the same thing with the emulator battery state UI but I didn't try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior may depend on your OS level.  On newer devices (API 23 and higher), we can find out if the battery is charging or discharging, even when a charger is connected.  On older devices, we use the presence of whether a charger is connected to determine if we are charging.

You can look at the exact behavior here if you're curious: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/constraints/trackers/BatteryChargingTracker.java

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and I found out you got to change both:

- `Charger connection` to `None`
- `Battery status` to `Not Charging`

just as below [image]

---

## Side note:

if you use `setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)` you got to put `Charger connection` to `NONE` in addition of lowering the `Charge level`.